# iOS Password Hash datatype in Core Data Database?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, hash

Alright, I was using the keychain API provided by the *Security.framework* to store the passwords for the user accounts in my app.  Unfortunately, the keychain API doesn't integrate well when your app is distributed via Cydia, and resides in the */Applications* directory because the login process appears to be broken.

I decided that I would just encrypt the the pin the user inputs into the pin text field, and store the pin as a hash in the Core Data database.  I know this isn't as secure as using the Keychain API, but I want to finish / release my app sometime this year.  So I added the necessary objects to the necessary classes to be able to store the pin in the database.  So my question is, why datatype should I use to store the password hash in the Core Data database.  I assuming a *String* would be the necessary choice, but just wanted to confirm with the SO crowd.

Here's a picture of what I am talking about,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Core Data `NSString`. Depending on what hash method you are wanting to use it will most likely be an alpha-numeric string.

`Binary` would be for pictures and stuff like that.

Comment: NSString isn't a choice, but I assuming you mean String

Comment: @Chris It is an NSString, when you build your NSManagedObject class it is an NSString. But yes, I mean string.